# Unable to connect to Wi-Fi using NetworkManager (reason 'no-secrets) in Debian 9

Tags: debian, networking, networkmanager

I'm using `Debian 9 Stretch (4.9)` and I use an Wi-Fi dongle (TL-WN823N V2) to connect to a Wi-Fi.

I've installed the driver using this [link](https://github.com/masterzorag/RTL8192EU-linux), and I got it working.

`iwconfig`

```
root@debian:/home/annahri# iwconfig
eno1      no wireless extensions.

wlx18d6c71536ac  unassociated  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency=2.417 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

I tried to connect to to my home wifi, I provided the correct password but I wasn't able to connect, it shows a pop-up that says something about "no secret provided".

And I got these lines in `journal -fa`

```
Aug 10 16:45:32 debian NetworkManager[499]: <info>  [1502358332.4690] device (wlx18d6c71536ac): Activation: starting connection 'Mastrip gg.4' (d5f0fb19-5e8c-46a1-8591-c4ae76d2be1e)
Aug 10 16:45:32 debian NetworkManager[499]: <info>  [1502358332.4694] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="d5f0fb19-5e8c-46a1-8591-c4ae76d2be1e" name="Mastrip gg.4" pid=812 uid=1000 result="success"
Aug 10 16:45:32 debian NetworkManager[499]: <info>  [1502358332.4701] device (wlx18d6c71536ac): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Aug 10 16:45:32 debian NetworkManager[499]: <info>  [1502358332.4704] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Aug 10 16:45:32 debian NetworkManager[499]: <info>  [1502358332.4739] device (wlx18d6c71536ac): set-hw-addr: reset MAC address to 18:D6:C7:15:36:AC (preserve)
Aug 10 16:45:32 debian NetworkManager[499]: <info>  [1502358332.4779] device (wlx18d6c71536ac): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Aug 10 16:45:32 debian kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx18d6c71536ac: link is not ready
Aug 10 16:45:32 debian NetworkManager[499]: <info>  [1502358332.4814] device (wlx18d6c71536ac): Activation: (wifi) access point 'Mastrip gg.4' has security, but secrets are required.
Aug 10 16:45:32 debian NetworkManager[499]: <info>  [1502358332.4815] device (wlx18d6c71536ac): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
Aug 10 16:45:32 debian NetworkManager[499]: <info>  [1502358332.5716] device (wlx18d6c71536ac): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none') [60 40 0]
Aug 10 16:45:32 debian NetworkManager[499]: <info>  [1502358332.5738] device (wlx18d6c71536ac): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Aug 10 16:45:32 debian NetworkManager[499]: <info>  [1502358332.5743] device (wlx18d6c71536ac): Activation: (wifi) access point 'Mastrip gg.4' has security, but secrets are required.
Aug 10 16:45:32 debian NetworkManager[499]: <info>  [1502358332.5743] device (wlx18d6c71536ac): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
Aug 10 16:45:32 debian NetworkManager[499]: <info>  [1502358332.6280] device (wlx18d6c71536ac): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none') [60 40 0]
Aug 10 16:45:32 debian NetworkManager[499]: <info>  [1502358332.6307] device (wlx18d6c71536ac): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Aug 10 16:45:32 debian NetworkManager[499]: <info>  [1502358332.6327] device (wlx18d6c71536ac): Activation: (wifi) access point 'Mastrip gg.4' has security, but secrets are required.
Aug 10 16:45:32 debian NetworkManager[499]: <info>  [1502358332.6341] device (wlx18d6c71536ac): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
Aug 10 16:45:32 debian NetworkManager[499]: <info>  [1502358332.6775] device (wlx18d6c71536ac): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none') [60 40 0]
Aug 10 16:45:32 debian NetworkManager[499]: <info>  [1502358332.7014] device (wlx18d6c71536ac): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Aug 10 16:45:32 debian NetworkManager[499]: <info>  [1502358332.7019] device (wlx18d6c71536ac): Activation: (wifi) access point 'Mastrip gg.4' has security, but secrets are required.
Aug 10 16:45:32 debian NetworkManager[499]: <info>  [1502358332.7020] device (wlx18d6c71536ac): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
Aug 10 16:45:32 debian NetworkManager[499]: <info>  [1502358332.7582] device (wlx18d6c71536ac): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none') [60 40 0]
Aug 10 16:45:32 debian NetworkManager[499]: <info>  [1502358332.7590] device (wlx18d6c71536ac): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Aug 10 16:45:32 debian NetworkManager[499]: <info>  [1502358332.7594] device (wlx18d6c71536ac): Activation: (wifi) access point 'Mastrip gg.4' has security, but secrets are required.
Aug 10 16:45:32 debian NetworkManager[499]: <info>  [1502358332.7595] device (wlx18d6c71536ac): state change: config -> failed (reason 'no-secrets') [50 120 7]
Aug 10 16:45:32 debian NetworkManager[499]: <info>  [1502358332.7598] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Aug 10 16:45:32 debian NetworkManager[499]: <warn>  [1502358332.7613] device (wlx18d6c71536ac): Activation: failed for connection 'Mastrip gg.4'
```

But when I tried to connect using `wicd`, I successfully connected to my home wifi. I just curious why `NetworkManager` fails to connect because `no secrets provided`.

Comment: I do remember seeing something about limitations using open wifi SSIDs in some settings...cannot be of further help.

Comment: Same problem (couldn't connect) with NetworkManager although log showed a different reason.  wicd works.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try activating the connection using "nmtui":
[image]
(the “*” means activated).

And make sure you have correct password by editing the connection.
[image: edit connection]
This worked for me.

Comment: This could work but I can't test it because I already changed my distro. Yet this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? What is the new distro name? Do you still face the same issue in the new one also?

Comment: I'm using Solus now, with no problem concerning this. But, I appreciate your answer. It might work for others. I was asking why NetworkManager was unable to connect to a network because "no secrets provided".